# Blazor Azure WebApp Wont Start - Socket Exception 10013 - Works Fine on Home Server

Tags: exception, websocket, blazor-server-side, azure-webapps, .net-7.0

I have a home server and deploying blazor on it works without issue. Im running windows 11 on the home server - dedicated pc. When I try to deploy to azure webapp it deploys just fine. But when I try to start the .exe i get this error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCtSN.png)

Im using kestrel from MS.

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(httpsOptions =>
    {
        httpsOptions.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls13;
    });

    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443, e =>
    {
        e.UseHttps("######.pfx", "#######");
        e.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2AndHttp3;
    });
});
```

I tried everything. Spent hours on this issue.
Please help. Thank you.

I tried everything!!!

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/649527/does-azure-app-service-tls-ssl-settings-protocol-s and https://tutorialsforcloud.com/2021/07/23/setting-minimum-tls-version-for-azure-app-services/

Comment: Thank you for that link. I went over the information but it did not fix the issue. No matter if I set tls to 1.2 or 1.3 in azure or in Program.cs code the error is the same. The .exe wont start in Azure. On azure console I try to start the exe but get this error every single time. I also tried restarting azure web app, creating a new web app and so on.

Comment: As of 03-08-2023 -- Problem is still not solved. Please help.

Comment: Revalidate the file paths for the certificate, firewall config & passwords before executing

Comment: I did verify all 3. Everything looks good. When I deploy a brand new blazor project it works fine. Then when I deploy the actual project it wont load. So I doubt its the firewall settings or certificate.

When I try to execute the exe to start blazor thats when i get errors and it wont load.

Comment: Can anyone help with this issue?